# Promise.map.map chain fails when there's concurrency but passes unit tests

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I naively assumed I can just chain a `.map()` off a `Promise.map()` but it appears I'm wrong.  I get the annoying issue of passing unit tests but failing real world tests when concurrency is high.  I think this makes this a gotcha worth noting on Stack Overflow.

I changed the code to use the usual `.then()` pattern and it appears to work every time now.

Is the issue here that unlike arrays in JS I cannot chain a `.map()` off a `Promise.map()` or was I doing something else wrong?  I note I cleaned up a few lint issues in the working version, but that doesn't seem to have made a difference in behavior.

Below is code that fails randomly (when concurrency is high) and one that appears to work all the time in low concurrency unit tests.  Note all functions called return promises.

```
// this has concurrency issues. occasionally the function
// returns [{ key: undefined: val: correct }]
db.assocThreeFewCountsGet = function(manyid, atype) {
  counts = [];
  return db.assocThreeFewDistinctGet(manyid, atype)
  .then(r => {
    console.log('Distinct', r);   // shows there are valid IDs
    counts = r;
    return Promise.map(r, fewid => {
      return db.assocCount(manyid, fewid);
    }).map((el, idx) => {
      return { key: counts[idx], val: el };
    });
  });
};

// this appears to work correctly.  key: and val: are correct
db.assocThreeFewCountsGet = function(manyid, atype) {
  var ids;
  return db.assocThreeFewDistinctGet(manyid, atype)
  .then(r => {
    ids = r;
    console.log('Distinct IDs:', ids);  // shows there are valid IDs
    return Promise.map(ids, fewid => {
      return db.assocCount(manyid, fewid);
    });
  }).then(counters => {
    return counters.map((el, idx) => {
      return { key: ids[idx], val: el };
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: What is your goal? What does `assocCount` do, does it mutate `r`?

Comment: The goal is really to just combine the IDs from one table (DistinctGet) to the counts in a different table (countGet).   None of the functions called mutate.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would not work. What is `idx` in the callback function? Can you also `console.log(JSON.stringify(counts))` before and inside the loop, please?

Comment: the second argument to Promise.map and Array.map is the index.  One of the things I'm trying to determine from this question is whether that second .map() is a Promise.map or an Array.map.  If it's an Array.map it might explain the problem because it binds before the Promises are resolved?

Comment: As far as a repro to get more debug info... it repros in a place that greatly annoys the manager.  If I could repro it in a unit test, I would love that... but can't figure out how.

Comment: It's a `Promise.prototype.map` and should not call its callbacks before the respective promise resolves.

Comment: If you cannot provide an example that reproduces the behaviour, we have to assume that it is a race condition. That [global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) `counts` variable really throws me off - I bet something *is* mutating it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141389/discussion-between-paul-s-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `counts = [];` assignment is suspicious and seems to [create a global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). That would cause all sorts of issues, including `counts` referring to the latest array in concurrent executions of the asynchronous method. Also in your working code, you have `var ids` for the same purpose, which is local to each call.

If you don't need `counts` anywhere else, fix your code by using

```
db.assocThreeFewCountsGet = function(manyid, atype) {
  return db.assocThreeFewDistinctGet(manyid, atype)
  .then(counts => {
    console.log('Distinct', counts);   // shows there are valid IDs
    return Promise.map(counts, fewid => {
      return db.assocCount(manyid, fewid);
    }).map((el, idx) => {
      return { key: counts[idx], val: el };
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: that's likely it.  In prod this is called 10 times in parallel, in testing, once.  Ugh.  I thought I had ES6 turned on by default (node 7.7.3).  "use strict" is now going in everywhere and I'm delinting now.  How embarrassing.  Thank you for your time..

Comment: per our conversion and per the original question, the second `.map()` in the first non-working version and your example is fine, it's a `Promise.prototype.map`.  I did google for that and couldn't find the answer, so now, there's an answer at least.